# Reset inputs in the previous form for a Jquery Mobile Multi Page Application

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, jquery-mobile

I developed an application using Jquery Mobile with multi pages (each one has an individual  form) in a single html file.

And I haven't figure out until now how I can clear all fields of a previous form when the 
button Back (type data-rel="back" located on page header) is pressed, and the previous form is showed.

My flow is similar as described bellow:

1. Show page Login
2. On Login page fill fields (user, password),  validate the form and submit it.
3. After submit, change page for second page (Same HTML, data-role="page" )
4. After press Back Button on the second page (not browser), the Login page 
   still showing all input fields filled.

I saw a lot of snippets but not in particular related with this issue and when I tried 
to apply some of them I didn't get the clue to solve this.

Someone could help, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clear the fields each time the form is visited you can simply use the pagebeforeshow event:

```
$('#page1').on('pagebeforeshow', function (event, data) {
    //clear fields here    
});
```

If you only want to clear the fields when coming back from the second page, the same event has a second argument which tells you where you are coming from.

```
$('#page1').on('pagebeforeshow', function (event, data) {
    var prevPageID = $(data.prevPage).attr("id");
    if (prevPageID == "page2"){
       //clear fields   
    }
});
```

API doc can be found here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/